# How to concat multiple text files that were updated in the last 12 hours into one

Tags: 16.04

How can i concat **all text files that were updated in a directory in the last 12 hours** into one

Comment: `cat file1 file2 > file3`

Comment: no i need to concat all files that were updated in the last 12 hhours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find _dir_ -mmin 720 -exec cat {} \; >>_single_file_
```

This will find all files in *dir* that have been modified in the last 720 minutes (12 hours) and cat them out.  The append to _single_file_ means they all get concatenated to one file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Must add - before 720 that is -720

Answer (score 0):

Tested OK

```
find <folder-path> -mmin -720 -type f -exec cat {} + >> <file-name>
```